# Compute $\lim\limits_{n\to{+}\infty}{{(2+n^3)}^{55-7n}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Find: $$\lim_{n\to{+}\infty}{{(2+n^3)}^{55-7n}}$$ 
According to Maple, that is equal to zero.
What theorem could I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put: $ y = {{(2+n^3)}^{55-7n}} $, then taking the natural log of both sides gives $$ \ln (y) = (55-7n)\ln(2+n^3) $$

Now, take the limit of both sides of the above equation:

$$ \ln (\lim_{n \to \infty} y) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (55-7n)\ln(2+n^3) = - \infty $$

Exponentiate both sides of the last equation:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} y = 0 .$$

Note that I used the following to find the limit: 
$$ (55-7n)\ln(2+n^3) = \left( 55-7\,n \right)  \left( 2\,\ln  \left( n \right) +2\,{n}^{-2}-
2\,{n}^{-4}+O \left( {n}^{-6} \right)  \right) 
 $$

Comment: Good answer +1.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\lim (2+n^3)^{55-7n}=\lim\frac{1}{ (2+n^3)^{7n-55}}$$

Now, what is $\lim 2+n^3$? And what is $\lim 7n-55$?

That should get you started.

Comment: $$\lim (2+n^3)=+\infty \quad \;;\;\quad \lim 7n-55=+\infty$$
Then, I get $$\frac{1}{{+\infty}^{+\infty}}.$$ But now, ¿how calculate ${+\infty}^{+\infty}.$?

Comment: @mathsalomon Well, you don't really get $\infty^\infty$. What that should be suggesting is that (after $7n>55$) you have to positive unbounded sequences, one which is raised to the power of another. This means that the limit of $P_n=a_n^{b_n}$ (the two sequences) will be $+\infty$ (meaning that given an arbitrarily large $M$ we can find an $N$ such that $P_n>M$). This means that we can make $1/P_n$ arbitrarily small, which means...

Comment: You mean I have to prove that $$a_n^{b_n}\to+\infty$$ using bounds?

Comment: @mathsalomon Well, the easiest route I see now is the squeeze theorem, with $$0<\frac{1}{ (2+n^3)^{7n-55}}<\frac{1}{n}$$ for $n>8$. What I was trying to tell you before was how to think what the behaviour of the sequences was without being too rigorous.